# How can I remove all instances of an element from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list `a`:

```
a = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [3, 3], [1, 1]]
```

Is there a function that removes all instances of `[1, 1]`?

Answer (score 53):

If you want to modify the list in-place,

```
a[:] = [x for x in a if x != [1, 1]]
```

Comment: Why set `a[:]` instead of just `a`?

Comment: @Raj: `a = [1]; b = a; a = [2]; b == [1]`; `a = [1]; b = a; a[:] = [2]; b == [2]`.

Comment: @Raj `a` isn't a box that you put objects in - it's a name tag that you tie to objects. `a = ...` ties the name tag to a new object, but `a[:]` replaces all items of the list that `a` is tied to with the contents of the new list.

Answer (score 25):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in a if x != [1, 1]]
```

Comment: I know writing `where` here is tempting, Ignacio, by analogy with SQL... but it doesn't work!  You have to spell it `if`, as I did in my answer.

Comment: @Alex: Argh, yes, right, fixed.

Answer (score 9):

Google finds [Delete all items in the list](http://old.nabble.com/Delete-all-items-in-the-list-td22222046.html), which includes gems such as

```
from functools import partial
from operator import ne
a = filter(partial(ne, [1, 1]), a)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `filter([1,1].__ne__, a)`?

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ That works for `list`, but `__ne__` doesn't exist as a method on `int` or some other types in Python 2.x.  This is fixed in Python 3.x, but for consistency...

Answer (score 7):

```
def remAll(L, item):
    answer = []
    for i in L:
        if i!=item:
            answer.append(i)
    return answer
```

Comment: thought it looks longer than others, but the code is actually clean, readable, and efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an easier alternative to Alex Martelli's answer:

```
a = [x for x in a if x != [1,1]]
```

Comment: This behaves differently - it will set the value of the variable but not modify the object. It appears to work, but doesn't modify the list - rather it replaces it. Anything that's using the old list won't get an update.

Answer (score 4):

```
new_list = filter(lambda x: x != [1,1], a)
```

Or as a function:

```
def remove_all(element, list):
    return filter(lambda x: x != element, list)

a = remove_all([1,1],a)
```

Or more general:

```
def remove_all(elements, list):
    return filter(lambda x: x not in elements, list)

a = remove_all(([1,1],),a)
```

Comment: Given what `list.remove` already does, I'd probably call this function `removeall`.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter([1,1].__ne__,a)
```

Comment: I do prefer `functools.partial(operator.ne,[1,1])`, because (at least in Python 2.x) other types (`int`, for example) don't all have `__ne__`.  That does appear to be fixed in Python 3, though: all types derive from `object`, which does have `__ne__`.

Answer (score -1):

pure python no modules version, or no list comp version ( simpler to understand ?)

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2]
>>> for item in xrange(x.count(1)):
...     x.remove(1)
...
>>>
>>> x
[2, 3, 2]
```

can be made into a def pretty easily also

```
def removeThis(li,this):
    for item in xrange(li.count(this)):
           li.remove(this)
    return li
```